# Laravel storage file request works on localhost but doesn't on production

Tags: laravel, server, get, localhost, storage

My file storage and management application in laravel gets files from storage and displays on the browser, this works fine on local as all get requests are successful but on production, only a few get requests are successful while others are not found. i checked the server storage and they are all present.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create storage soflink ?
if no than please run php artisan storage:link from ssh.

Comment: I have but its still not working, returns 404 for some files and 200 for some